# Magento - Security and brute force

Tags: security, magento, e-commerce, brute-force, magento-1.7

I'm trying to decide whether to use Magento or create my own platform and I was wondering about security. Does Magento's code include some sort of brute force protection? If not, is this not something important?

Comment: The benefit of going with a widely-used platform is that it constantly being used and tested in the wild. Rolling your own means that you will be the only tester and very easily could miss some things, even things besides brute force.

Answer (score 3):

**Protect your Magento Store to Brute force attacks. Follow following step.**

> **Apache Server Users**
>
> To whitelist an IP address for the admin panel, add the following rule in root .htaccess file (inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`)

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.xx
RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?admin/ - [L,R=403]
```

> To whitelist an IP address for the RSS feed, add the following rule in the root .htaccess file (inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>):`

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.xx
RewriteRule ^(index.php/?)?rss/ - [L,R=403]
```

> To whitelist an IP address for the downloader application, add the following rule in ./downloader/.htaccess file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Answer (score 2):

So I know this is an old thread but I found it searching for answers on how to protect Magento against brute-force attacks. The things have changed since 2012, so  I want to point the people looking for information about Magento security in (hopefully) the right direction.
Seems like Magento has finally decided to stop ignoring the problem of increasing number of brute-force attacks on Magento websites so they have published an official list of recommended steps on how to protect Magento from such attacks: https://magento.com/security/best-practices/protect-your-magento-installation-password-guessing 
Hosting companies also started offering solutions to block these hack attempts, from blocking and blacklisting IPs to installing filtering software.
There are also several security extensions including a good number of Two-Factor Authentication ones. In my opinion the most complete security extension currently available is MageFence by ExtensionsMall. Here's a link on Magento Connect: *magentocommerce[.]com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/30596/*. It has many useful features like scanning your website for malware and vulnerabilities, blocking IP addresses after too many failed login attempts and it comes together with Two-Factor Authentication module.You can also check out [MageFence page on ExtensionsMall website](http://www.extensionsmall.com/mage-fence-security.html) to get the idea of all the security holes this module will help you patch up.

Answer (score 0):

The only brute-force protection Magento has is in case of gift cards. When throwing exception there, Magento obscures real exception message (but puts it in logs) and shows 'Wrong gift card code' message instead.

When it comes to login forms, Magento has no brute force protection.

If this is an important factor for you when deciding whether use Magento or write your own platform, remember that you could write your own Magento module that introduces some brute force protection. This would be way less time-consuming than writing own platform with functionalities similar to Magento.

I did a quick search on the Magento Connect and found one extension that, among other things, provides brute force protection. Here it is: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/market-ready-germany.html. You can download it using [Freegento website](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and look into the code for clues on how to make something similar.